# iPhone multiple select menu multiple="multiple" always removes the last selected value

Tags: iphone, select, multi-select

I've got a bare page to test, and I'm trying to get a multiple select menu to work on the iPhone 4, 4S, 5. All display the same behaviour - you select your options, hit done, it reads "X items" and then it removes the last selected item and reads "(X-1) items". My code is as follows:

```
<form>
    <select name="multiselect-test" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="0">Please select...</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4">Option 4</option>
        <option value="5">Option 5</option>
        <option value="6">Option 6</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Anybody ever come across this before or able to suggest a fix?
Or is there something missing in my code?

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue. I would also add that if you don't select anything and click "Done", it will select the first option.